# How to setup tRPC project with pnpm

Tags: prisma, pnpm, trpc.io

I am trying to learn from [this repo](https://github.com/trpc/examples-next-prisma-starter).

Step 3 of the setup instructions says to run yarn dx.

The package.json for this repo defines that script as:

```
"dx": "run-p dx:* --print-label",
```

When I try to do this, I get an error message that says:

> yarn dx yarn run v1.22.19 $ run-p dx:* --print-label [dx:next
> ] $ run-s migrate-sqlite generate-sqlite db-seed && next dev
> [dx:prisma-studio] $ pnpm prisma-studio-sqlite [dx:prisma-studio]
> /bin/sh: pnpm: command not found [dx:prisma-studio] error Command
> failed with exit code 127. [dx:prisma-studio] info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command. ERROR: "dx:prisma-studio" exited with 127. error Command
> failed with exit code 1.

I'm not sure what pnpm means, or why prisma is trying to link to sqlite when the db it specifies is psql.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what's required to get this repo to start?

Answer (score 1):

If you use yarn, change any occurrence in the package.json from pnpm to yarn and I think it should work :)